# Put waypoints on a car

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the current version of Unity. I am developing a racing game.
My question is how to put waypoints on the track or car so that the car can follow the track around?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Wellcome to Stack Overflow! Try to add some code that you already have, so the people can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

To create waypoints on the track you can use empty game objects only visible on the editor.

If you want your car to follow these waypoints you will need to implement two things in your code:

- Turn to face the next waypoint
- Advance until hit the next waypoint

There are several video tutorials in youtube on how to start developing simple games in Unity. I highly recommend you to start with them.